# Expandable list view issue with toggle buttons(custom toggle with three state) loose its state while expanding group

Tags: android, button, toggle, expandablelistview

When i scrolling my list items its loose its states means 1st element row if on then after expanding second row other items shown on.

For your reference also attached my code.

**ExpListViewAdapterWithCheckBox.java**(Adapter class)

```
public class ExpListViewAdapterWithCheckBox extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

// Define activity context
private Context mContext;
private boolean toggleState;
/*
 * Here we have a Hashmap containing a String key
 * (can be Integer or other type but I was testing
 * with contacts so I used contact name as the key)
*/
private HashMap<String, List<String>> mListDataChild;
private ArrayList<Integer> selectedItemsList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
// ArrayList that is what each key in the above
// hashmap points to
private ArrayList<String> mListDataGroup;

// Hashmap for keeping track of our checkbox check states
private HashMap<Integer, boolean[]> mChildCheckStates;

// Our getChildView & getGroupView use the viewholder patter
// Here are the viewholders defined, the inner classes are
// at the bottom
private GroupViewHolder groupViewHolder;

/*
      *  For the purpose of this document, I'm only using a single
 *  textview in the group (parent) and child, but you're limited only
 *  by your XML view for each group item :)
*/

private String groupText;
private String childText;

/*  Here's the constructor we'll use to pass in our calling
 *  activity's context, group items, and child items
*/
public ExpListViewAdapterWithCheckBox(Context context, ArrayList<String> listDataGroup, HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild) {

    mContext = context;
    mListDataGroup = listDataGroup;
    mListDataChild = listDataChild;

    // Initialize our hashmap containing our check states here
    mChildCheckStates = new HashMap<Integer, boolean[]>();


}


@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return mListDataGroup.size();
}

/*
 * This defaults to "public object getGroup" if you auto import the methods
 * I've always make a point to change it from "object" to whatever item
 * I passed through the constructor
*/
@Override
public String getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return mListDataGroup.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}


@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    //  I passed a text string into an activity holding a getter/setter
    //  which I passed in through "ExpListGroupItems".
    //  Here is where I call the getter to get that text
    groupText = getGroup(groupPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_item, null);

        // Initialize the GroupViewHolder defined at the bottom of this document
        groupViewHolder = new GroupViewHolder();

        groupViewHolder.mGroupText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.groupTextView);

        groupViewHolder.mGroupText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }
        });


        convertView.setTag(groupViewHolder);
    } else {

        groupViewHolder = (GroupViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    groupViewHolder.mGroupText.setText(groupText);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return mListDataChild.get(mListDataGroup.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

/*
 * This defaults to "public object getChild" if you auto import the methods
 * I've always make a point to change it from "object" to whatever item
 * I passed through the constructor
*/
@Override
public String getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return mListDataChild.get(mListDataGroup.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {

    return childPosition;

}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final int mGroupPosition = groupPosition;
    final int mChildPosition = childPosition;

    //  I passed a text string into an activity holding a getter/setter
    //  which I passed in through "ExpListChildItems".
    //  Here is where I call the getter to get that text
    childText = getChild(mGroupPosition, mChildPosition);

    final ChildViewHolder childViewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_item, null);

        childViewHolder = new ChildViewHolder(convertView);


        convertView.setTag(R.layout.child_item, childViewHolder);

    } else {

        childViewHolder = (ChildViewHolder) convertView
                .getTag(R.layout.child_item);
    }

    childViewHolder.mChildText.setText(childText);

    /*
     * You have to set the onCheckChangedListener to null
     * before restoring check states because each call to
     * "setChecked" is accompanied by a call to the
     * onCheckChangedListener
    */
    //childViewHolder.mToggle.setOnScrollChangeListener(null);
    childViewHolder.mToggle.setFocusable(true);


    childViewHolder.mToggle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            if(childViewHolder.mToggle.getState().equals(FlashButton.FlashEnum.AUTOMATIC)){

                childViewHolder.mToggle.setState(FlashButton.FlashEnum.ON);
            }else if(childViewHolder.mToggle.getState().equals(FlashButton.FlashEnum.ON)){

                childViewHolder.mToggle.setState(FlashButton.FlashEnum.OFF);
            }else if(childViewHolder.mToggle.getState().equals(FlashButton.FlashEnum.OFF)){

                childViewHolder.mToggle.setState(FlashButton.FlashEnum.AUTOMATIC);

            }


        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {


    return false;
}

public void setToggleStatus(boolean status) {
    toggleState = status;
}

public ArrayList<Integer> getarray() {

    return selectedItemsList;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

class GroupViewHolder {

    TextView mGroupText;
}

class ChildViewHolder {

    TextView mChildText;
    FlashButton mToggle;

    public ChildViewHolder(View v) {
        mToggle = (FlashButton) v.findViewById(R.id.tstb_1);
        mChildText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.childTextView);
    }


}
```

}

also attached the code where i got logic for three state toggle.
**FlashButton.java**

```
public class FlashButton extends ToggleButton {

public enum FlashEnum {
    AUTOMATIC, ON, OFF
}

public interface FlashListener {
    void onAutomatic();

    void onOn();

    void onOff();
}

private FlashEnum mState;
private FlashListener mFlashListener;

public FlashButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int next = ((mState.ordinal() + 1) % FlashEnum.values().length);
            setState(FlashEnum.values()[next]);
            performFlashClick();
        }
    });
    //Sets initial state
    setState(FlashEnum.AUTOMATIC);
}

private void performFlashClick() {
    if (mFlashListener == null) return;
    switch (mState) {
        case AUTOMATIC:
            mFlashListener.onAutomatic();
            break;
        case ON:
            mFlashListener.onOn();
            break;
        case OFF:
            mFlashListener.onOff();
            break;
    }
}

private void createDrawableState() {
    switch (mState) {
        case AUTOMATIC:
            setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.timer15x);
            break;
        case ON:
            setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.onswitch1x);

            break;
        case OFF:
            setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.switchoff1x);

            break;
    }
}


public FlashEnum getState() {
    return mState;
}

public void setState(FlashEnum state) {
    if (state == null) return;
    this.mState = state;
    createDrawableState();

}

public FlashListener getFlashListener() {
    return mFlashListener;
}

public void setFlashListener(FlashListener flashListener) {
    this.mFlashListener = flashListener;
}
```

}

Is this problem of expandable Listview Or in my code do some changes to resolve it.